# ping request timed out one way

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I have two systems in my office LAN. One is running Fedora and the other windows 7.
I can ping the windows machine from the Fedora machine but I am unable to ping the Fedora machine  from windows machine. Whenever I ping the Fedora machine it gives a "Request timed out"
I tried disabling the firewall on Fedora machine but it did't help. Please suggest what could be the problem here.

Comment: Can the Fedora machine ping itself?

Comment: ... on its external interface?

Comment: Is the Fedora dropping ping requests? (iptables enabled?)

Comment: I am not able to ping Fedora machine with or without iptables enabled.

Comment: Do `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` - does it show 1? Then do `echo "0" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` and try ping again.

Comment: The Fedora machine can ping itself..both at the loop-back address and the other ip address

Comment: ott: Thanks! I checked but the command already shows a 0

Answer (score 0):

Ping replies are simply handled by an interrupt call in the Windows TCP/IP stack, therefore interaction with your server is quite limited. To send out the ping from Windows, though, it needs to know how to route the packet. Is your routing set up correctly? Can you see the network from your Windows box? Have you got the right IP address for your Fedora box?

(I edited this to get the Windows/Fedora thing the right way round, but the basic point remains the same - as has also been said, replying to a ping and sending a ping out are not the same)

Comment: There is no problem with the windows box because I can ping my windows box from my Fedora box. It is not working the other way round.

Comment: The process of pinging and replying to a ping are different, hence the question about routing.  My guess would be routing also.  A ping reply just pushes the reply back out the same interface it came in on.  So my guess is the Windows box routing is wrong.